# xinput: Disable mapping touchscreen on external monitors

Tags: arch-linux, x11, i3, xinput, touch-screen

I am using Arch linux with i3wm on my Lenovo x390 YOGA. I also have two external monitors. I connect them throw my docking station and configure with Arandr. Screens woks fine.

But every time I connect to external monitors my cursor triples it's sensitivity on horizontal axis. My laptop's touch screen divides in to thirds and maps monitors on each.

There is output of `xinput --list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                            id=2  [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger      id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus  id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                  id=17 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                      id=18 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser  id=22 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DP-2                                        id=9  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Generic ThinkPad Dock USB Audio Control     id=20 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                           id=3  [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                id=8  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C             id=14 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I             id=15 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=16 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                      id=19 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DP-2                                        id=10 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Generic ThinkPad Dock USB Audio             id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Generic ThinkPad Dock USB Audio Control     id=21 [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This making the touch screen nearly unusable. How can I disable this function ?

Thank you for help

**PS:** If you need any more information, ask in comments and I will provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add this code to your `~/.config/i3/config`:

```bsh
# Map input devices only to embedded screen
exec --no-startup-id xinput --map-to-output 13 eDP1     #Wacom finger
exec --no-startup-id xinput --map-to-output 12 eDP1     #Wacom pen
exec --no-startup-id xinput --map-to-output 22 eDP1     #Wacom pen eraser
exec --no-startup-id xinput --map-to-output 17 eDP1     #Touchpad
exec --no-startup-id xinput --map-to-output 18 eDP1     #Trackpoint
```